# object is not shown in CategoryView

Tags: python, django

I wrote in top.html

```
<div>
    <a href="#">
       Category
    </a>
    <div>
         {% for category in category_content %}
             <a  href="{% url 'category' category.name %}">
                 {{ category.name }}
             </a>
         {% endfor %}
   </div>
</div>
```

in category.html like

```
<div>
     {% for content in queryset %}
        <h2>{{ content.title }}</h2>
        <a  href="{% url 'detail' content.pk %}">SHOW DETAIL</a>
     {% endfor %}
</div>
```

When I put  in top.html,no error happens and page is shown but no  `<h2>{{ content.title }}</h2>` is shown here.
I wrote in views.py

```
class CategoryView(ListView):
    model = Category
    template_name = 'category.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        category_name = self.kwargs['category']
        self.category = Category.objects.get(name=category_name)
        queryset = super().get_queryset().filter(name=self.category)
        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.all()
        return context

def category(self,pk):
    queryset = self.base_queryset()
    category = self.kwargs.get("category")
    queryset = queryset.filter(category__name=category)
    return queryset
```

in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('top/', views.top, name='top'),
        path('category/<str:category>/',views.CategoryView.as_view(), name='category'),
    ]
```

in models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Index(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to show list of Index data that are by filtered Category  in my db in category.html .For example, it is my ideal system ,when I put Python link in top.html,content.title which is related with Python is shown in  category.html .But now no content.title is shown.What is wrong in my code?How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoud add filtered Index list to the context first:

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    context['categories'] = Category.objects.all()
    context['index_list'] = Index.objects.filter(category=self.category)
    return context
```

Now `index_list` will be available inside template and you can do this:

```
<div>
 {% for content in index_list %}
    <h2>{{ content.title }}</h2>
    <a  href="{% url 'detail' content.pk %}">SHOW DETAIL</a>
 {% endfor %}
</div>
```